# How to efficiently append a dataframe column with a vector?

Tags: dataframe, append, julia

Working with Julia 1.1:

The following minimal code works and does what I want:

```
 function test()
    df = DataFrame(NbAlternative = Int[], NbMonteCarlo = Int[], Similarity = Float64[])
    append!(df.NbAlternative, ones(Int, 5))
    df
 end
```

Appending a vector to one column of `df`. Note: in my whole code, I add a more complicated `Vector{Int}` than `ones'` return.

However, `@code_warntype test()` does return:

```
%8  = invoke DataFrames.getindex(%7::DataFrame, :NbAlternative::Symbol)::AbstractArray{T,1} where T
```

Which means I suppose, thisn't efficient. I can't manage to get what this `@code_warntype` error means. More generally, how can I understand errors returned by `@code_warntype` and fix them, this is a recurrent unclear issue for me.

EDIT: @BogumiłKamiński's answer
Then how one would do the following code ?

```
for na in arr_nb_alternative
    @show na
    for mt in arr_nb_montecarlo
        println("...$mt")
        append!(df.NbAlternative, ones(Int, nb_simulations)*na)
        append!(df.NbMonteCarlo, ones(Int, nb_simulations)*mt)
        append!(df.Similarity, compare_smaa(na, nb_criteria, nb_simulations, mt))
    end
end
```

`compare_smaa` returns a `nb_simulations` length vector.

Comment: This is not an answer, but note that `Array{Int,1}===Vector{Int}`, which is shorter and more clear.

Comment: @OscarSmith, oh thank you very much, I didn't know that! That's useful haha

Comment: also `Matrix` is an alias for `Vector{T,2}`

Comment: @OscarSmith did you mean Array{T,2}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never do such things as it will cause many functions from DataFrames.jl to stop working properly. Actually such code will soon throw an error, see https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/1844 that is exactly trying to patch this hole in DataFrames.jl design.

What you should do is appending a data frame-like object to a `DataFrame` using `append!` function (this guarantees that the result has consistent column lengths) or using `push!` to add a single row to a `DataFrame`.

Now the reason you have type instability is that `DataFrame` can hold vector of any type (technically columns are held in a `Vector{AbstractVector}`) so it is not possible to determine in compile time what will be the type of vector under a given name.

**EDIT**

What you ask for is a typical scenario that DataFrames.jl supports well and I do it almost every day (as I do a lot of simulations). As I have indicated - you can use either `push!` or `append!`. Use `push!` to add a single run of a simulation (this is not your case, but I add it as it is also very common):

```
for na in arr_nb_alternative
    @show na
    for mt in arr_nb_montecarlo
        println("...$mt")
        for i in 1:nb_simulations
            # here you have to make sure that compare_smaa returns a scalar
            # if it is passed 1 in nb_simulations
            push!(df, (na, mt, compare_smaa(na, nb_criteria, 1, mt)))
        end
    end
end
```

And this is how you can use `append!`:

```
for na in arr_nb_alternative
    @show na
    for mt in arr_nb_montecarlo
        println("...$mt")
        # here you have to make sure that compare_smaa returns a vector
        append!(df, (NbAlternative=ones(Int, nb_simulations)*na,
                     NbMonteCarlo=ones(Int, nb_simulations)*mt,
                     Similarity=compare_smaa(na, nb_criteria, nb_simulations, mt)))
    end
end
```

Note that I append here a `NamedTuple`. As I have written earlier you can append a `DataFrame` or any data frame-like object this way. What "data frame-like object" means is a broad class of things - in general anything that you can pass to `DataFrame` constructor (so e.g. it can also be a `Vector` of `NamedTuples`).

Note that `append!` adds columns to a `DataFrame` using **name matching** so column names must be consistent between the target and appended object.

This is different in `push!` which also allows to push a row that does not specify column names (in my example above I show that a `Tuple` can be pushed).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm sorry but I still don't get how I should do what I put in the edit of my question, which is also the title of it. Should I create a new dataframe for each `append!`?

Comment: I have expanded the answer to match the question after your edit :).

Comment: I suppose you have too many parenthesis in your last code example but except this, it's totally working, thank you!

Comment: Fixed. I was writing it from my head and did not run it to test. Sorry.